# I need help for make a if (*(char*)

Tags: c++

i need help

I make a SPRX (plugin PS3) and i want if the offset contain the hex / char it's can enable my code

My exemple:

```
if (*(char*)0x00000000 == 0x00) {
//CODE
}
```

This exemple work it's read the offset on my memory but, i want add more hex like 0x00, 0x00

When i try that, it's not work

I don't know if something like this can work:

```
char HEX[] = { 0x3F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x80 };

if (*(char*)0x00000000 == HEX) {
//CODE
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Read about [`std::memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) or, for a higher level solution, [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).

Comment: You want to see if the 10 contiguous bytes of memory that start at a certain address are equal to a given pattern?

Comment: Actualy the first code (exemple) work but it's read only 1 hex on the offsets (address) i want it's read more hex like 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

Comment: You may want to use `uint8_t` instead of `char` since `char` may be a signed type.

Comment: I have try on uint8_t, same it's not work

Comment: `*(char*)0x00000000` is dereferencing a null pointer, which is undefined behavior and likely to crash

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer to reflect your new information in the comment:

```
    char hex[]{ 0x3F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x80 };

    //Check if array equal to another array at address
    char* addr = (char*)0x30000ABE4;
    bool same = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if (addr[i] != hex[i]) {
            same = false;
        }
    }
    if (same) {
        cout << "RUN CODE" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Alex, thanks you but i don't know how to use it i'm bad on C++ my PS3 read the offset (address) = 0x3000ABE4 and the char is: Misaki i want if the offset contains Misaki my code is enabled. My code ```if (*(char*)0x3000ABE4 == 0x00)``` work but i can't add more hex it's my problem :/

Comment: @Sakira57 Check my updated answer. Put that code into your program and test it out

Comment: Omg thanks you so much it's work i will make some test if i see something wrong i tell you thanks you so much !!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer as correct, or upvote it if it works if you don't mind!

Comment: I have tested it all work, thanks you very much and yes i will do have a great day !

Comment: @Sakira57 Haha don't forget to accept the answer!! You too!!